# Makefile target errors

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I have been reading a book on SFML game development and they use unique_ptr's.  And to use them I know that I must use the -std=c++11 flag when compiling, however I have been having issues doing this with a Makefile.  Below is a copy of my Makefile:

```
flags = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

main: main.cpp texture_holder.o
    g++ main.cpp texture_holder.o -o Run $(flags) -std=c++11

texture_holder: texture_holder.cpp texture_holder.h
    g++ texture_holder.cpp -c -std=c++11

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o Run
```

When just typing **make** I get errors about unique_ptr not being a member of std.  But what I can't figure out, is that when I type **make texture_holder** texture_holder.cpp does compile just fine then running **make** builds the application.  Do I have something ordered wrong or am I missing anything?  If it helps, I can attach the code that I am using, but like I said, it builds just fine when I build the texture_holder target first.

Comment: Look closely at the output from `make`. It will show you exactly what commands (with all flags) it's executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong rule for `texture_holder.o`, it should be this:

```
texture_holder.o: texture_holder.cpp texture_holder.h
        g++ texture_holder.cpp -c -std=c++11
```

Ie. including the `.o` extension.

---

What happens with your question's version is, when you do `make texture_holder`, you execute that particular rule, which does not actually create corresponding file `texture_holder`, it creates `texture_holder.o`, because well, that's what the commend produces. The `texture_holder` rule is effectively a phony rule, similar to `main` and `clean` (and btw, you should add `main` to `.PHONY` too).

If you `make main`, then to create `texture_holder.o`, *make* uses *implicit rule* (because there is no explicit one), which uses different compile command.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I have never actually had to add the .o extension for a target, and that is why I could not figure it out.  I will accept this answer once I am able to.

Comment: I hope the section I added explains what's going on, but if it does not, feel free to ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You have a rule for making `texture_holder`, not `texture_holder.o`. The rule for `main` will attempt to make `texture_holder.o` using the default compilation rule, not your special one. The default rule won't specify `-std=c++11`, hence the error.